# Conditional Formating macro gives me Run-time error 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Open an excel sheet

Type **Orange** into **A1** cell

Type **Banana** into **A2** cell

Type **15** into **B1** cell

Type **23** into **B2** cell

Go to **Developer** Tab and then click **Record Macro** button

Click **OK** in order to record a macro.

Select **A1 and A2** cells together

Go to **Home** tab > **Conditional Formating** > **New Rule** > **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**

Type **=B1>12**

Click **Format** button

Click **Number** tab

Click **Custom** button

Type **"    "@**

Click **OK** button

Click **OK** button again

Go to **Developer** Tab and then click **Stop Recording** button

Press **Alt+F11** in order to see following macro.

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("A1:A2").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = """""@"
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=B1>12"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
ExecuteExcel4Macro "(2,1,""""""@"")"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

You will see the error (**Run-time error 1004**) when you run the macro you recorded.

Do you know how to solve **Run-time error 1004**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little research and I found your solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2010/conditional-format-macro/7209fbc4-5594-4462-8226-318b7f0821ea) The macro recorder is reverting to the old ExecuteExcel4Macro command in order to set the number format for the conditional formatting rule. This is not necessary.

Below how your code should look like:

```
Sub Macro1()

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A2")
     .FormatConditions.Delete 'Removes all the rules from the selection first
     .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=B1>12"
     .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
     .FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = """""@"
     .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
End Sub
```